# Как авторизоваться к группе вк по token?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь подключиться к группе вк вот так:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

session = vk_api.VkApi(token = 'da1a7d724884c8da')
vk = session.get_api()
bot_longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(session, '185')
```

Но выдает вот такую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/111111111/fft.py", line 6, in <module>
    bot_longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(session, '182442355')
  File "\Python\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 207, in __init__
    self.update_longpoll_server()
  File "\Python\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 220, in update_longpoll_server
    response = self.vk.method('groups.getLongPollServer', values)
  File "\Python\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 636, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: no access to call this method
```

В чем проблема? До этого получалось от страницы подключаться, но недавно и со страницей стало происходить такое, хотя в коде подключения от страницы ни строчки не сменил.

Comment: vk политику поменяли

Comment: со страницей точно https://vk.com/dev/messages_api

Answer (score 1):

С 15 февраля 2019 года секция messages (с ключом пользователя) заблокирована. Есть 3 варианта:

1. Создаём новый ключ пользователя без секции messages
2. Используем ключ сообщества.
3. Идём в [поддержку](https://vk.com/support?act=new_api) и просим выдать права доступа.

Сам лично столкнулся с этой проблемой. Я пошёл 2 способом.

[Вот здесь](https://vk.com/dev/messages_api) чуть-чуть по подробнее